# How do I install Postgres 9.4 on Cygwin?

Tags: postgresql, cygwin, downgrade

I upgraded all my packages with `setup` but 9.5 said it was incompatible with 9.4. (https://serverfault.com/questions/532379/how-do-i-upgrade-postgres-database-in-cygwin) I tried to downgrade to 9.4 to export the DB, but it gave me an error when I tried to start it.

I tried to install version 9.4.4-2 of Postgres with ftp://www.fruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/circa/2015/09/25/151012/index.html, but now it won't start. I also tried to install 9.4.4-1 but that won't work either. I also tried to exit all Cygwin processes and run 'dash' and 'rebaseall', but it didn't help. How do I install an old version of Postgres 9.4 to upgrade to 9.5?

```
$ /usr/sbin/postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.4.4

$ /usr/sbin/postgres
FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Function not implemented
DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=5432001, size=40, 03600).

$ /setup-x86 -X -q -P postgresql-9.4.4-1
note: Hand installation over to elevated child process.

$ /usr/sbin/postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.4.4

$ /usr/sbin/postgres
FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Function not implemented
DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=5432001, size=40, 03600).
```

Comment: Forgot to restart cygserver. Admin terminal: `cygrunsrv -S cygserver`

Comment: OMG Thank you! @Chloe!